# How do I grab the elements in a form in Angular and have them appended in a list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm new to Angular and want to create a basic list where I enter in an item name and price and click "Add item" and have it appended to a list. I have everything set up, but I'm not sure why the name and price are not displaying when I click add item: http://jsfiddle.net/ov671be3/3/

```
<body ng-app="split">
<div ng-controller="check">
    <form>
        <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="item name">
        <input type="text" ng-model="price" placeholder="item price">
        <input type="button" ng-click="addToList(name, price)" value="Add item">
    </form>
</div>

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in myItems">{{item.name}} - {{item.price}}</li>
</ul>

<script>
    var split = angular.module("split", [ ]);

    split.controller('check',['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.myItems = [];
        $scope.addToList = function(name, price) {
            $scope.myItems.push({name:name, price:price});
        }
    }]);


</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't assigned anything to a model?

Comment: I'm not certain how to do that? @MatthewGreen My fiddle link is up if you can show me.

Comment: Model's are the basic foundation of angularjs. If you aren't sure about that I would start with the docs and go from there. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup a repeater, a click event, and an array to hold the items:

```
split.controller('check',['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.myItems = [];
    $scope.addToList = function(name, price) {
        $scope.myItems.push({name:name, price:price});
    }
}]);
```

And setup your view with models:

```
<div ng-controller="check">
    <form>
        <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="item name">
        <input type="text" ng-model="price" placeholder="item price">
        <input type="button" ng-click="addToList(name, price)" value="Add item">
    </form>
</div>

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in myItems">{{item.name}} - {{item.price}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I copied your code, but I'm not getting the items to list, can you show me in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```
<body ng-app="split">
    <div ng-controller="check">
        <form ng-submit="addItem()">
            <input type="text" ng-model="item.name" placeholder="item name">
            <input type="text" ng-model="item.price" placeholder="item price">
            <input type="submit" value="Add item">
        </form>
        <h3>Here is the list: {{list}}</h3>
    </div>
    <script>
        var split = angular.module("split", [ ]);
        split.controller('check',['$scope', function($scope){
                $scope.list = [];
                $scope.person = "Payam"
                $scope.addItem = function(){
                    $scope.list.push($scope.item);
                };
        }]);
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ngModel to bind the values of the inputs to a value that you can access from Angular. Then you can use ngRepeat to display all of the item objects in an array that you also store. Here's a quick redo of your form.

```
<body ng-app="split">
    <div ng-controller="check">
        <input type="text" placeholder="item name" ng-model="itemForm.name">
        <input type="text" placeholder="item price" ng-model="itemForm.price">
        <input type="button" value="Add item" ng-click="itemForm.add()">
        <h3>Here is the list:</h3>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in itemForm.list">
                Name: {{ item.name }}, Price: {{ item.price }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script>

        angular.module("split", [ ])

        .controller('check',['$scope', function($scope){
            $scope.itemForm = {
                list: [],
                add: function () {
                    this.list.push({
                        name: this.name,
                        price: this.price
                    });
                    this.reset();
                },
                reset: function () {
                    this.name = '';
                    this.price = '';
                }
            };
            $scope.itemForm.reset();
        }])

        ;

    </script>
</body>
```